# Why Addition Assignment (+=) works between a list and a string but concatenation doesn't?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If I have any list x

```
x=[]
```

When adding a string (iterable) to it, it doesn't work

```
x = x + 'welcome'
```

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list*

While addition assignment works

```
x+='welcome'
```

```
['w', 'e', 'l', 'c', 'o', 'm', 'e']
```

Comment: `+=` is the same as `extend` which takes any iterable.